# POWER BI: I can embed reports but not dashboards

Tags: access-token, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

So here is my situation:
i managed to embed Reports in our web application. i registred Native App to avoid all the redirection process. So i'm getting the accessToken from the backend. Using that accessToken: i can make calls to the powerBi api: get dashboards, reports etc...
i 'm also able to embed reports using the javascript client (v2.2.6).
but if i'm embedding a dashboard using the same accessToken: the dashbaord is not loaded. using the network view of firebug: im seeing a bunch of 401 unauthorized responses.
When i use a token acquired by authorization code (app registered as Web Client): i'm able to embed the dashboard.
Is there anyone who managed to embed dashboard using a token of a native App?

Comment: exactly: the tutorial uses the get token by authorization code. that means there is a redirection and login process which i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, reports worked but not dashboards. It seams when `tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed` is passed through in the embed config to the embed function, a *XHR* request down the line returns `403`. By removing this option, the report loads.

The new dashboard functionality will only be launched later this year and then the option above can be sent through.